# Compaction cause OutOfMemoryError

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I'm getting OutOfMemoryError when run compaction on some big sstables in production, table size is around 800 GB, compaction on small sstables is working properly though.

```
$ noodtool compact keyspace1 users
error: Direct buffer memory
-- StackTrace --
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Direct buffer memory
        at java.nio.Bits.reserveMemory(Bits.java:693)
        at java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.<init>(DirectByteBuffer.java:123)
        at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(ByteBuffer.java:311)
        at org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.BufferType$2.allocate(BufferType.java:35)
```

Java heap memory(Xms and Xmx) have been set to 8 GB, wondering if I should increase Java heap memory to 12 or 16 GB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the Heap size, but it's instead so-called "direct memory" - you need to check what amount you have (it's could be specified by something like this `-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=512m`, or it will take the same max size as heap). You can increase it indirectly by increasing the heap size, or you can control it explicitly via `-XX` flag.  Here is the [good article](https://dzone.com/articles/troubleshooting-problems-with-native-off-heap-memo) about non-heap memory in Java.